# Trying to sort the output of a .txt file in ascending order by by the AccountName in Shell Scirpt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I have created a simple bash script that will ask the user to enter in an AccountName, DOB, Username, Password and Email address and these details are being redirected to a text file called Register.txt and from here I am trying to sort the contents of the Register.txt file in ascending order based on the usernames. I have tried various approaches to try and solve this problem however I have had no luck. Any assistance and guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated as I have run out of ideas.

here is the bash script I have put together for taking in these details.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "Welcome, This Is The Registration Form Associated With Option 1"

echo "--------------------------------------------"
echo "Please Enter In The Requsted Details Below"
echo "-------------------------------------------- \n"

#Taking in the users Registration Information
read -p "Please Enter Your Full name (Forename and Surname): " AccountName
read -p "Please Enter Your Date of Birth in the format (DD/MM/YYY): " DOB
read -p "Please Enter The Username You Would Like To Have While Using The System: " Username
read -p "Please Enter The Password You Want To Associate With This Account: "  Password
read -p "Please Enter The Email Address You Want To Associate With This Account: " Email

#Redirecting The Users Account Registration Information to a text file called Register.txt
echo "Full Name: "$AccountName"\n""Date Of Birth: "$DOB"\n""Account Username: 
"$Username"\n""Account Password: "$Password"\n""Registered Email Address: "$Email >> 
Register.txt

#Sorting contents of Regsiter.txt in ascending order by Username

# Code here? #
```

Here is the sample contents of the Register.txt file:

```
Account Name: Joe Bloggs
Date Of Birth: 31/03/1987
Account Username: JoeyB
Account Password: Test0
Registered Email Address: joebloggs@gmail.com

Account Name: Anna Bloggs 
Date Of Birth: 17/11/1975
Account Username: AnnaTheBlogga
Account Password: Test1
Registered Email Address: annaB@hotmail.com

Account Name: Faith Bloggs
Date Of Birth: 01/04/2000
Account Username: FaithThePreacher
Account Password: Test2
Registered Email Address: Faith2000@gmail.com
```

Comment: What is the _**output** of a txt file_? An output is something generated by a program. As for sorting of text files, see _man sort_.

Comment: Assuming you want to sort the blocks by the `Account Name` in dictionary order, which has higher priority of first name and last name? What if one has middle name?

Comment: As `Account Name:` is the first to appear in each block then you could do something like `awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n\0' 1 Register.txt | sort -z | tr -d '\0'`

Comment: @tshiono For this simple case I'm just working with first and last names as I'm pretty new to the world of Bash scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `awk` script to sort `Register.txt`

```
awk '{print $2, $4, $6, $8, $10}' RS="" FS=": |\\n" OFS="|"  Register.txt | sort
```

#### Output:

```
Anna Bloggs |17/11/1975|AnnaTheBlogga|Test1|annaB@hotmail.com
Faith Bloggs|01/04/2000|FaithThePreacher|Test2|Faith2000@gmail.com
Joe Bloggs|31/03/1987|JoeyB|Test0|joebloggs@gmail.com
```

#### Explanation:

`RS=""` Set `awk` record separator to be empty line.

`FS=": |\\n"` Set `awk` field separator to be `newline` **or** `:` .

`OFS="|"` Set `awk` output field separator to be `|`.

`{print $2, $4, $6, $8, $10}` Output even `awk` fields (2,4,6,8,10).